# Computing $e^x$ in Octave using only +,-,*,/,^.

Tags: algorithms, octave

I have to write a function in Octave which is computing e^x. I wrote this:

```
function y=f(x)
    y=0; t=1; k=1;
        while abs(t)>0.001
        y=y+t;
        t=t*(x/(2*k));
        k=k+1;
        end
    y=y^2;
end;
```

Everything is okay when I'm computing $f(20)$ or $f(-30)$ etc. But when I try to compute $f(-2000)$ I should get $ \approx 0$, but Octave says it's $\infty$. Is it my fault (I mean something's wrong with code)?

Comment: The problem is floating point numbers are not real numbers. And for large negative numbers, there is much cancelation in this code. See http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf

Comment: have you tried debugging? (like printing the intermediates each loop)

Comment: To compute $e^x$ with taylor expansion, manage to use only small $x$. To achieve this, use $e^x=\left(e^{x\over n}\right)^n$, so that argument in power series may be kept small. You allready use this $n=2$, but you have to chose a $n$ near $x$.

Comment: Also consider computing $e^{-x} = 1 / e^x$ to avoid cancellations. Or use a [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) algorithm for kicks...

Comment: Just curious: Why the restruction?

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of arbautjc's comment, given the operators you have, you can always ensure that the magnitude of the argument is less than $1$. Furthermore if $x<0$, you can do as vonbrand suggested and use index laws to aid your calculations. This will likely be much slower than simply using the `exp(..)` command built in.

The following is MATLAB code, but it should work in Octave as well.

```
function y = myexp(x)
    % determine if x is negative or not
    if (x < 0)
        isneg = true;
        x = -x;
    else
        isneg = false;
    end

    % scale the input variable to have magnitude less than 1
    scale = 1; % initialise the scale argument
    factor = 16; % set a factor which will be used to increment the scale
    while x > 1
        x = x / factor;
        scale = scale * factor;
    end

    % evaluate exp(x) with 0<x<1
    y=0; t=1; k=1; % initialise parameters
    tol = 1e-6; % convergence tolerance
    while abs(t)>tol
        y=y+t;
        t=t*(x/k);
        k=k+1;
    end

    % unscale the result
    y=y^scale;

    % check if the input was negative and reciprocate the result if needed
    if isneg
        y = 1/y;
    end
end
```

Some results are below. `V` is value and `T` is execution time. `tol` was set to `1e-6`.

```
x=-100
exp V: 3.720076e-44 T: 0.000004
myexp   V: 3.720262e-44 T: 0.000059
x=-10
exp V: 4.539993e-05 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 4.540017e-05 T: 0.000021
x=-5
exp V: 6.737947e-03 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 6.737952e-03 T: 0.000016
x=-4
exp V: 1.831564e-02 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 1.831572e-02 T: 0.000016
x=-3
exp V: 4.978707e-02 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 4.978711e-02 T: 0.000016
x=-2
exp V: 1.353353e-01 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 1.353358e-01 T: 0.000016
x=-1
exp V: 3.678794e-01 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 3.678795e-01 T: 0.000015
x=0
exp V: 1.000000e+00 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 1.000000e+00 T: 0.000016
x=1
exp V: 2.718282e+00 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 2.718282e+00 T: 0.000016
x=2
exp V: 7.389056e+00 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 7.389029e+00 T: 0.000016
x=3
exp V: 2.008554e+01 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 2.008552e+01 T: 0.000016
x=4
exp V: 5.459815e+01 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 5.459791e+01 T: 0.000017
x=5
exp V: 1.484132e+02 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 1.484131e+02 T: 0.000016
x=10
exp V: 2.202647e+04 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 2.202635e+04 T: 0.000017
x=100
exp V: 2.688117e+43 T: 0.000002
myexp   V: 2.687982e+43 T: 0.000016
```